# How to give struct objects random not matching x and y coordinates in C?

Tags: c, arrays, coordinates

I am trying to do my homework, which is some sort of game.
This is a part of it and I'm trying to create a function which puts 18 (9 in one team and the other 9 in another) different players on the field. player is a struct which has a name and coordinates. So I tried to write this function and had several problems. I think I have mostly fixed them, but I don't understand what's wrong with it now. Basically this function gives all the players random x and y coordinates, but as I have to make sure that they don't match, I created 2 lists x's and y's. The program takes all the players and add's their x coordinates to x's list if the current player x coordinate matches any x coordinates in x's list, then the program checks the same player's y coordinate and checks if it matches the coordinate of y of the same object in y's list. So if both x and y math, then the program runs again by recursion. The problem I get is that the coordinates I get every time I run the program are same. they don't match but they are not really random cause they don't change when I run them again.

I think I have tried all my knowledge and skills but still can't understand the problem of my code.
Can you please tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
void random_positions()
{
    int i,j;
    int xs[17],ys[17];
    for(i= 0; i<9 ; i++)
    {
     players[i][0].x = rand() % 25;
     players[i][0].y = rand() % 25;
     players[i][1].x = rand() % 25;
     players[i][1].y = rand() % 25;
     printf("A%d x = %d y = %d \n",i+1,players[i][0].x,players[i][0].y);
     printf("B%d x = %d y = %d \n",i+1,players[i][1].x,players[i][1].y);          
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
          xs[i] = players[i][0].x; 
          xs[i+8] = players[i][1].x;
          ys[i] = players[i][0].y; 
          ys[i+8] = players[i][1].y;
          for(j = 0; j <= i ; j++)
          {
                //printf("j%d start\n",j);
                if(i != j && xs[i] == xs[j])
                {
                     //printf("i%d start\n",j);
                     if(ys[i] == ys[j])
                     {
                              return random_positions();                                    
                     }
                     //("j%d done\n",j);
                }
                //printf("j%d done\n",j);
          }  
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'always the same result' sounds like you are not seeding the random number generator on each run.  It also sounds as if you're enforcing the rule 'no two players can start in the same column, and no two players can start in the same row', which is a much more stringent condition than 'no two players can start in the same position'.

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe that was the problem. I tried so many different things and nothing worked. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computer is (usually) a deterministic machine; if you run the same program twice, you will get the same answer.

A random number generator generally takes a *seed*, an initial value that it uses to initialize itself before it starts producing random numbers; give it a different seed, and you will get a different sequence. One way to do this is to give it the current time as a seed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));

  /* generate random number between 1 and 10: */
  int num = rand() % 10 + 1;

  printf("%d\n", num);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 (other than `<<` will not work as I/O in C as posted)

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for posting this kind of simple question, I just couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: @chux: Thank you, that was careless of me; I'll edit.